# Vuforia Ground Plane Detection doesn't work when using webcam (IP webcam using Iriun Webcam in android phone)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, webcam, vuforia

Thought of using Vuforia as it allows testing using a webcam. So, i downloaded Iriun Webcam (IP Webcam for android), and succesfully got the video stream inside the Unity Editor when i press "Play".
I created a minimal AR example, where my app would detect a plane and a tap would place an object.
My issue is that when I Build the apk and test it on my phone it works perfectly as it should, but when i do it using the play button inside the editor, the video stream is captured, but it won't do any AR stuff (like plane detection as it was supposed to do)

Please help me with any possible reason there could be, as I couldn't find any such issues faced by anyone else

I created a minimal AR example, where my app would detect a plane and a tap would place an object.
My issue is that when I Build the apk and test it on my phone it works perfectly as it should, but when i do it using the play button inside the editor, the video stream is captured, but it won't do any AR stuff (like plane detection as it was supposed to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here https://library.vuforia.com/unity-extension/vuforia-play-mode-unity Ground Plane is not supported when using a webcam in Unity Play Mode. Ground plane relies on a robust device tracker and this is not available when using a webcam.  However, to help development, it is possible to record a sequence on a device and then using this in play mode https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/recording-and-playback. The other option is to emulate the Ground Plane behavior using an Image Target as discussed here https://library.vuforia.com/ground-plane/introduction-ground-plane-unity.

Comment: Good info about the recording a sequence and playback